# Wordpress Universal Plugin 404 error

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress Universal Plugin - Corporate theme, but i am getting so many 404 errors like:

wp-content/themes/universal-wp/admin/inc/extensions/customizerextension_customizer.min.js?ver=2.0.0

the "/" is missing here:

customizer/extension_customizer.min.js

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Wordpress Universal Plugin - Corporate theme doesn't exist… are you sure?

Comment: it exists, the 404 error i am getting is because there is a missing "/" in 
customizerextension_customizer.min.js 
instead of 
customizer/extension_customizer.min.js

Comment: Solution could be going to settings > permalinks. change it to something else, apply it. then revert to your setting apply it again. This will generate some code in your .htaccess file to make clean urls… if it not works, try to find in your theme files where these js files are registered with the function `wp_enqueue_script()` and correct the url adding the missing `/`. It seems like a bug in your theme. You can also warn themes author in their support threads.

Comment: i searched the whole theme code where they register the css and js, but not able to find anything.